# How do you separate /bin and /sbin when making an RPM?

Tags: compiling, rpm

I'm trying to make a redis RPM using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)

When I run the following commands, all binaries are installed to /tmp/installdir/usr/local/bin

```
cd /tmp/redis2-8
PREFIX=/tmp/installdir/usr/local/ make 
PREFIX=/tmp/installdir/usr/local/ make install
```

How could I compile redis so that the `redis-server` binary is installed to `/tmp/installdir/usr/local/sbin` and everything else (`redis-cli, redis-benchmark` ect.. ) is installed to `/tmp/installdir/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: [Are you sure you want to?](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-October/158845.html)

Comment: Well, no.., but that is how many other packages are created. Example = mysqld and mysqladmin. I'm trying to make this rpm as "correctly" as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fpm` dev [has this to say](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) on the subject of distribution-specific guidelines:

> I want a simple way to create packages without all the bullshit. In my own infrastructure, I have no interest in Debian policy and RedHat packaging guidelines - I have interest in my group's own style culture and have a very strong interest in getting work done.
>
> (This is not to say that you can't create packages with FPM that obey Debian or RedHat policies, you can and should if that is what you desire)

So, the default behavior you are observing, where everything is placed in `/usr/local/bin` seems to be the group's preference. And they are not alone; not only Fedora & co but also [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) agree with merging `/bin` and `/sbin` into `/usr/bin`. While the [current draft](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs.html#usrsbinNonessentialStandardSystemBi) of the FSH still uses `sbind` directories, there does seem to be a movement building against them.

In any case, the Fedora people have some [very good arguments](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-October/158845.html) against `sbin` which include (emphasis mine):

> a) the split between sbin and bin requires psychic powers from
>   upstream developers:
>
> The simple fact is that moving binaries between these dirs is really    hard, and thus developers in theory would need to know at the time    they first introduce a binary whether it *ever* might ever make sense to    invoke it as unprivileged user (because in that case the binary    belongs in /bin, not /sbin). **History shows that more often than    not developers have placed their stuff in the wrong directory, see    /sbin/arp, /sbin/ifconfig, /usr/sbin/httpd** and then there is no smart    way to fix things anymore since changing paths means breaking all hardcoded    scripts. And hardcoding paths in scripts is actually something we    encourage due to perfomance reasons. The net effect is that many    upstream developers unconditionally place their stuff in bin, and    never consider sbin at all which undermines the purpose of sbin    entirely (i.e. **in systemd we do not stick a single binary in sbin**,    since we cannot be sure for any of its tools that it will never    ever be useful for non-root users. and systemd is as low-level,    system-specific it can get).
>
> b) The original definition of /sbin is fully obsolete (i.e. the "s" in
>   sbin stood originally for "static" binaries)
>
> c) /bin vs. /sbin is not about security, never has been. Doing this
>   would be security by obscurity, and pretty stupid, too.
>
> d) **splitting /bin off /sbin is purely and only relevant for $PATH, and
>   $PATH is purely and only something to ease access to the tools in it for shell users. The emphasis here is on "ease". It is not a way to make it harder for users to access some tools.** Or in other words: if your intention is to hide certain tools from the user in order not to confuse him, then there are much better places for that: the documentation could document them in a separate section or so. I don't think it makes any sense at all trying to educate the user by playing games with what he can see if he presses TAB in the shell. [...]

These points were made about `/sbin`, but they seem equally applicable to `/usr/local/sbin`. So, while @slm gave you what I'm sure is the way to do what you're actually asking for, it might be better to just ignore `sbin` and let `fpm` do its thing.

Comment: I don't understand what is supposed to be *obsolete* about statically linked binaries? It makes sense that a systemd developer would thank so, though, given the enormous dependency chain upon which it is built, But I *like* using minimal toolsets for purposeful tasks - and I *really* like doing `strace` on a statically linked process.

Comment: Oh  wait a minute, I get it: Lennart is implying the *need* is obsolete because the dynamic libs are always available because systemd *solved all of that*. That guy is a peacock.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take control of where various files will be installed you'll have to take responsibility for manually doing this within your RPM `.spec` file directly.

#### Example

Here's a snippet from a JBOSS RPM `.spec` file that I created in a blog series I wrote up a couple of years ago. The article in this series is titled: [CentOS RPM Tutorial Part 3 - Building your own RPM of JBoss](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6837/centos-rpm-tutorial-part-3-building-your-own-rpm-of-jboss/).

```
...
%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install
rm -fr $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -m 0755 -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/%{name}/%{name}-%{version}
cp -R * $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/%{name}/%{name}-%{version}

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%post
echo " "
echo "install of jboss complete!"

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/opt/%{name}/*
...
```

In the above `%install` stanza you'll need to specify where in your `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` you'd like the software to be "installed" to. Here's where you can make your `sbin` and `bin` directories respectively.

When categorizing the files you've "installed" with this RPM, you'll need to reflect their locations in the `%files` section. You can facilitate this a bit by creating bulid macros in your `$HOME/.rpmmacros` file if you find you're making the same ones all the time.

For example, I have a `%_topdir` macro that I use when building things, like so:

```
%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
```

These macros can then be utilized in your `.spec` files.