# ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist

Tags: boot, systemd, manjaro

I've installed Linux Mint and Manjaro Linux on my computer. I installed only the Linux mint on the MBR. For Manjaro, I created a `/boot/efi` partition, but I have not checked to install to MBR.

So, I am controlling `grub` from mint. Now, when I try to boot Manjaro, it shows :

```
ERROR: resume: no device specified for hibernation: performing fsck on
dev/sda11  /dev/sda11: clean 1727/915712 files, .... blocks

WARNING: The root device is not configured to be mounted read-write!It
may be fsck'd again later

:mounting /dev/sda11 on real boot running cleanup hook [udev]

ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.

sh:can't access tty; job control turned off

[rootfs /]#
```

After the shell prompt, I can't write anything. It hangs, or sometimes it shows me messages continuously like :

```
usb 3-3: device not accepting address 2, error -62
```

and so on...

I tried to add  `init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` to grub, as I saw in google, but still the same.

I must note that for the Manjaro installation I am using a separate partition for `/` and for `/usr` and for `/var`.
This maybe have an influence? As I saw [here](http://spartha.org/2013/06/06/arch-linux-systemd-upgrade-issues/) .

But the problem is that I can't write anything, it hangs.

I also found a comment on a blog post [here](http://spartha.org/2013/06/06/arch-linux-systemd-upgrade-issues/comment-page-1/#comment-209) that states:

> “If you keep /usr as a separate partition, you must adhere to the following requirements:
>   “ - Add the shutdown hook. The shutdown process will pivot to a saved copy of the initramfs and allow for /usr (and root) to be properly unmounted from the VFS.
>
> “ - Add the fsck hook, mark /usr with a passno of 0 in /etc/fstab. While recommended for everyone, it is mandatory if you want your /usr partition to be fsck’ed at boot-up. Without this hook, /usr will never be fsck’d.
>
> “ - Add the usr hook. This will mount the /usr partition after root is mounted. Prior to 0.9.0, mounting of /usr would be automatic if it was found in the real root’s /etc/fstab.”
>
> And never forget to run mkinitcpio -p linux every time after you make changes to mkinitcpio.conf to actually create the new images and get them the right place.

That sounds promising since my `/usr` is indeed on a separate partition. What are these "hooks" and how do I add them?

`parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  ntfs            Basic data partition  hidden, diag
 2      1075MB  1347MB  273MB   fat32           Basic data partition  boot
 3      1347MB  1482MB  134MB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftres
 4      1482MB  80,1GB  78,6GB  ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
 5      80,1GB  80,4GB  262MB   ext4
 6      80,4GB  90,4GB  10,0GB  ext4                                  msftdata
 7      93,0GB  102GB   9000MB  ext4                                  msftdata
 9      102GB   106GB   3999MB  linux-swap(v1)
10      106GB   106GB   250MB   fat32                                 boot
11      106GB   121GB   15,0GB  ext4                                  msftdata
12      121GB   151GB   30,0GB  ext4                                  msftdata
13      151GB   165GB   14,0GB  ext4                                  msftdata
14      165GB   206GB   40,9GB  ext4                                  msftdata
 8      206GB   743GB   537GB   ext4                                  msftdata
15      743GB   747GB   4000MB  linux-swap(v1)                        msftdata
```

`grub`:

```
menuentry 'Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit, 3.13.0-24-generic (/dev/sda5)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  19af2e09-8946-4ca2-9655-75921f3609a5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 19af2e09-8946-4ca2-9655-75921f3609a5
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=9356f543-f391-4ba5-9dcc-e8484d6935e0 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
menuentry 'Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit, 3.13.0-24-generic (/dev/sda5) -- recovery mode' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  19af2e09-8946-4ca2-9655-75921f3609a5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 19af2e09-8946-4ca2-9655-75921f3609a5
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=9356f543-f391-4ba5-9dcc-e8484d6935e0 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}


menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (0.8.10) (on /dev/sda11)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt11'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt11 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt11 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt11  95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-312-x86_64 root=/dev/sda11
    initrd /boot/initramfs-312-x86_64.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Manjaro Linux (0.8.10) (on /dev/sda11)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6' {
    menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (0.8.10) (on /dev/sda11)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-312-x86_64--95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt11'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt11 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt11 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt11  95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 95ed019d-9269-4869-9f99-a03f002a53c6
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-312-x86_64 root=/dev/sda11
        initrd /boot/initramfs-312-x86_64.img
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite hard to debug since you have a relatively complex setup. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo parted -l` and the contents of your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file (or at least the Manjaro entry).

Comment: OK, and are you sure that `/dev/sda11` actually contains manjaro's root file system? Have you correctly set up the `/etc/fstab` on the manjaro system to mount the other partitions you need? Can you confirm that there is a `/sbin/init` on `/dev/sda11`?

Comment: @terdon:First of all , I don't have access to manjaro , only to mint.I am now with live cd in manjaro and as I can see there is a /sbin/init. The /etc/fstab contains only /dev/mapper/root-image and dev/sda9 swap  (but I am with live cd)

Comment: You need to mount the drive in Mint. Run `mkdir foo && sudo mount /dev/sda11 foo` from Mint. Then check whether the contents of `~/foo` look like a `/` directory, make sure there is a `~/foo/sbin/init` and check ~/foo/etc/fstab` to make sure that the partitions are loaded correctly when in Manjaro.

Comment: @terdon:It looks like a root directory but if I do cd ~/foo/sbin/ ,it shows no such file or dir.If I do cd ~/foo and then cd /sbin ,then it's ok and it contains the init.The fstab seems ok.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from [here](http://spartha.org/2013/06/06/arch-linux-systemd-upgrade-issues/)? You have `init=/usr/lib/systems/systems` in your question, that should be `init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` instead.

Comment: @terdon:Yes, I used systemd ( I have a typo).I didn't understand though in that post ,when one user says "-Add the shutdown hook. "...Add the fsck hook, mark /usr with a passno of "

Comment: @terdon In ArchLinux `/sbin` is now a symlink to `/usr/bin`. @George That blog comment references [that part of the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Initramfs#.2Fusr_as_a_separate_partition). In your case the problem may be the last bullet point. You need `/usr` to be mounted by the init ramdisk.

Comment: @Leiaz:Ok, but I have no idea how to do this.Note also that I don't have access to manjaro!

Comment: What @Leiaz said makes a lot of sense but first make sure it is the case. If `/sbin` is actually a symlink to `/usr/bin`, you shouldn't have seen a `/sbin/init` file when you mounted `/dev/sda11`. Mount the partition at `~/foo` again and tell us the output of `file ~/foo/sbin` and `file ~/foo/sbin/init`.

Comment: @terdon:The first output "broken symbolic link to usr/bin",The second "ERROR: cannot open ../foo/sbin/init/ no such file or dir"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Leiaz very correctly pointed out in the comments, `/sbin` in Arch (and by extension, Manjaro) is now a symlink to `/usr/bin`. This means that unless `/usr` is mounted, `/usr/sbin/init` will not exist. You therefore need to make sure that `/usr` is mounted by the initial ramdisk. That's what the Arch wiki quote in your OP means:

> If you keep /usr as a separate partition, you must adhere to the following requirements:
>
> - Enable mkinitcpio-generate-shutdown-ramfs.service or add the shutdown hook.
> - Add the fsck hook, mark /usr with a passno of 0 in /etc/fstab. While recommended for everyone, it is mandatory if you want your /usr partition to be fsck'ed at boot-up. Without this hook, /usr will never be fsck'd.
> - Add the usr hook. This will mount the /usr partition after root is mounted. Prior to 0.9.0, mounting of /usr would be automatic if it was found in the real root's /etc/fstab.

So, you need to generate a new init file with the right hooks<sup>1</sup>. These are added by changing the `HOOKS=""` line in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`. So

1. Boot into Mint and mount the Manjaro `/` directory:

   ```
   mkdir manjaro_root && sudo mount /dev/sda11 manjaro_root
   ```

   Now, Manjaro's root will be mounted at `~/manjaro_root`.
2. Edit the `mkinitcpio.conf` file using your favorite editor (I'm using `nano` as an example, no more):

   ```
   sudo nano ~/manjaro_root/etc/mkinitcpio.conf
   ```

   Find the `HOOKS` line and make sure it contains the relevant hooks

   ```
   HOOKS="shutdown usr fsck"
   ```

   **Important**" : do not remove any of the hooks already present. Just add the above to those there. For example, the final result might look like

   ```
   HOOKS="base udev autodetect sata filesystems shutdown usr fsck"
   ```
3. Mark `/usr` with a passno of 0 in `/etc/fstab`. To do this, open `manjaro_root/etc/fstab` and find the `/usr` line. For this example, I will assume it is `/dev/sda12` but use whichever one it is on your system. The "pass" number is the last field of an `/etc/fstab` entry. So, you need to make sure the line looks like

   ```
   /dev/sda12  /usr  ext4  rw,errors=remount-ro     0      0
                                                           ^
                            This is the important one -----|
   ```
4. Create the new init image. To do this, you will have to mount Manjaro's `/usr` directory as well.

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda12 ~/manjaro_root/usr
   ```

   I don't have much experience with Arch so this might not bee needed (you might be able to run `mkinitcpio` without a `chroot`) but to be on the safe side, set up a `chroot` environment:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev ~/manjaro_root/dev && 
   sudo mount --bind /dev/pts ~/manjaro_root/dev/pts && 
   sudo mount --bind /proc ~/manjaro_root/proc && 
   sudo mount --bind /sys ~/manjaro_root/sys &&
   sudo chroot ~/manjaro_root
   ```

   You will now be in a chroot environment that thinks that `~/manjaro_root/` is actually `/`. You can now go ahead and generate your new init image

   ```
   mkinitcpio -p linux
   ```
5. Exit the `chroot`

   ```
   exit
   ```
6. Update your `grub.cfg` (again, this might not actually be needed):

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Now reboot and try booting into Manjaro again.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Hooks" are small scripts that tell `mkinitcpio` what should be added to the init image it generates.

Comment: :When I enter "mkinitcpio -p linux" ,it gives me "ERROR: Preset not found /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset

Comment: @George Are there any preset in `/etc/mkinitcpio.d/` ? `linux` is the default on Archlinux, maybe Manjaro gives it another name.

Comment: @terdon:First of all it works fine!I had to use 'linux312' (the kernel)  instead of 'linux'.It still gives me the "WARNING: The root device..." I have in my first lines of my post but I think this is ok?And lastly , can you point me to some books or tutorials to learn this kind of stuff? :) . I want to be able to do these things also :).And i really appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: Huh.  I thought the entire point of `/sbin` was that it didn't have to be on the same partition as `/usr`.  I wonder why Arch decided to merge them?

Comment: @terdon:Something last!I need to do all this for every kernel update?And also the reason in the firstplace to have to do all these was that I had separate partitions for root and usr?

Comment: @George my main reference for this answer was the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Initramfs#.2Fusr_as_a_separate_partition), I highly recommend you read it. Yes, the problem was that you had `/usr` on a separate partition and no, you shouldn't need to do it again, next time the hooks will be added automatically because of the changes you made to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`.

Comment: @NateEldredge this is a general trend, I expect many distributions will do this. Have a look at my answer here: [How do you separate /bin and /sbin when making an RPM?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125311)

Comment: I'm confused. Why is /usr still fsck'd even though it has a passno of 0?

Comment: @JeffreyLin I'm not entirely sure myself. Presumably, the `fsck` hook forces the fsck but I don't know why a passno of `2` isn't recommended instead.

Comment: I kept mine at two, and it still seems to fsck at boot.

Comment: @JeffreyLin that does seem reasonable but I tend to trust the Arch Wiki. There may be other considerations we don't know about.

Answer (score 2):

From Mint, you can [change root](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot) to your Manjaro installation, in order to regenerate initramfs.

Mount your Manjaro root under the directory of your choice ( `~/foo`). Mount your `/usr` partition at `~/foo/usr`, also mount boot if it is separate.
Mount proc sys dev :

```
# mount -t proc proc ~/foo/proc/
# mount --rbind /sys ~/foo/sys/
# mount --rbind /dev ~/foo/dev/
```

And change root : `chroot ~/foo /bin/bash`

As explained in the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio) : "Hooks are small scripts which describe what will be added to the image". Edit `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, add the `usr` `fsck` and `shutdown` hooks to the `HOOK` entry, as indicated in the wiki and comments.
Regenerate initramfs : `mkinitcpio -p linux` (it will be written in `/boot`)

Exit the chroot, unmount proc, sys, dev and Manjaro partitions and try rebooting.

Comment: :Thank you for your help.terdon gave me much details in order to achieve the result :) .(upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

Just wasted around 6 hours creating a USB boot device for Linux Mint, backing up all my data from 2 partitions, and attempting various rescue attempts after getting the dreaded sbin/init not found message...

This happened after a minor update - system would not reboot. It seems the whole sbin folder had mysteriously been deleted and could not be recovered. The only meaningful advice I could find was 're-install'.

The fix, (less than 5 minutes!!) was as follows:

1. boot from the **original** live installation disk (Cinnamon Mint 17.1 in this case),
2. open a file explorer as root (either right click a folder and select 'open as root', alternatively open a terminal and type 'sudo nemo'
3. locate the live installation's sbin folder
4. mount the defective Mint partition (click on the icon)
5. change the permissions applying to the sbin folder (right click, Properties, Permissions, Others, File access, read and write - then click 'Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files')
6. copy the whole sbin folder into the installed root directory (/). (This is where the system 'bin', 'boot', 'home', 'usr' etc. folders are located.)
7. Reboot

Comment: I also have weird a minor update, it places all the kernel on my opened dir by root, awkwardly it on www folder