# /sbin/init doesn't exist - Bailing out

Tags: arch-linux, boot, systemd

My question is [similar to this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139802/error-root-device-mounted-successfully-but-sbin-init-does-not-exist), but has a few differences. At boot, I get the following message:

```
[    0.030164] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
:: running early hook [udev]
starting version 223
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents...
:: performing fsck on '/dev/sda8'
sda8: clean, ...
:: mounting '/dev/sda8' on real root
:: running late hook [usr]
:: performing fsck on '/dev/sda5'
sda5: clean, ...
:: mounting /dev/sda5 on /usr
:: running cleanup hook [shutdown]
:: running cleanup hook [udev]
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/e4rat-preload does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs /]#
```

(It says the same thing if I tell GRUB to use `/sbin/init` or `/bin/systemd`.)

As suggested by the accepted answer in the other question, I chroot'd into the Arch install using a live-CD, added the correct hooks to *mkinitcpio.conf*, marked `/usr` with a passno of 0 in /etc/fstab, and recreated the init image using `mkinitcpio -p linux-ck`.

It seems to have worked, but the result is still the same and I am now unable to chroot into the system.

```
$ arch-chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

**`sudo parted -l`**:

```
sudo parted -l /dev/sda
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  fat32        EFI System Partition          boot, esp
 2      1075MB  270GB   268GB   ntfs         Windows 10                    msftdata
 3      270GB   484GB   215GB   ntfs         Jeffrey                       msftdata
 4      484GB   484GB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 5      535GB   589GB   53.7GB  ext4
 6      589GB   643GB   53.7GB  ext4
 7      643GB   696GB   53.7GB  ext4
 8      696GB   750GB   53.7GB  ext4         Arch
```

**`/etc/fstab`**

```
# /dev/sda5
PARTUUID="4495844c-bbf3-4be0-a2f3-7d143077a2ed"        /usr                  ext4          ro,relatime                                                                                      0 2

# /dev/sda6
PARTUUID="23a5589e-5e88-40a3-9497-d3da166f3d4a"        /tmp                  ext4          rw,relatime,noexec,nosuid                                                                        0 0

# /dev/sda7
PARTUUID="07a6f06a-87f2-405e-a3d7-d26c5085041e"        /mnt/bindir           ext4          rw,relatime,nosuid                                                                               0 2

/mnt/bindir/root                                       /root                 none          bind                                                                                             0 0
/mnt/bindir/var                                        /var                  none          bind                                                                                             0 0
/var/home                                              /home                 none          bind                                                                                             0 0
/tmp                                                   /var/tmp              none          bind                                                                                             0 0

# /dev/sda1
PARTUUID="e532f9e3-ccd5-4edf-a8b0-35069e8afb35"        /boot                 vfat          rw,relatime,umask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro        0 0

# /dev/sda2
PARTUUID="f373613c-9b70-42c1-8266-d5774b212ef"         /mnt/Windows          ntfs-3g       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,users,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show                              0 0

# /dev/sda3
PARTUUID="e8fd05ac-9496-40fb-af01-01b41958fd41"        /mnt/Jeffrey          ntfs-3g       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,users,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show                              0 0
                             0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran `ldd /mnt/usr/bin/bash`, I noticed that some required libraries were missing. I copied the contents of `/usr/lib` in the live CD to `/usr/lib` on my computer. Now I was able to chroot into my installation.

I downloaded the snapshot of Linux-ck from the AUR, edited the .config to suit my needs, and compiled the kernel. Then, I ran `mkinitcpio -p linux-ck` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Afterwards, I was able to boot into a partially working system. It seems like I was missing some packages, and the packages that were installed had missing files, determined with `pacman -Qk`. I tried to reinstall all packages with [`pacman -Qenq | pacman -S -`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_tips#Reinstalling_all_packages), but that didn't work because pacman's database was corrupt. I had to [restore the local database](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_tips#Restore_pacman.27s_local_database), which also solved the previous problem.

At present, the only thing that still doesn't work is GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

I see:

```
mounting '/dev/sda8' on real root
```

Shouldn't you have an entry in your fstab for /dev/sd8 for the / directory. I see all your other mount points other than your actual root.

Comment: I had it commented out. Adding it in does nothing.

Comment: At the prompt can you access /bin/bash before the arch-chroot?

Comment: I can access /usr/bin/bash but not /mnt/usr/bin/bash, sh, zsh. I can access fish, but fail to run command /usr/bin/fish in chroot.

Comment: The entry for `/` in `/etc/fstab` is not directly relevant. It isn't used to mount the root partition at boot time — the root partition has to be mounted before the file can be read. The entry for `/` can be used to set different mount options. It might influence the automatic generation of the bootloader configuration or of an initrd/initramfs; I don't know if it does on Arch.

Comment: @Gilles I believe that / is first mounted, and is later remounted with the proper options sometime during the boot process.